# Webpack production build removes my exported function

Tags: typescript, webpack

I have a typescript application with a single index.ts file and it contains:

```
let options = {
  serverUrl: 'https://example.com/',
};

export function logOptions() {
  console.log('log options: ', options);
  return options;
}
```

but when I run `npm run build` ("build": "webpack") outputted file inside the public directory is empty.

but if I call this function inside `index.ts`, generated file looks like this:

```
(()=>{"use strict";var o;o={serverUrl:"https://example.com/"},console.log("log options: ",o)})();
```

So to sum up I have two problems:

1. I don't want to log this function, so why the output is empty
2. My function disappears, I need it to call later from another javascript web project.

Here's my webpack.config.js

const path = require('path');

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  mode: 'production',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
  },
  output: {
    publicPath: 'public',
    filename: 'prod.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
  },
  devServer: {
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    },
  },
};
```

And tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```